# Execute a read command

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a little script that I use to send bash commands to several web servers under a load balancer.  I'm able to send the command successfully, but I also want to execute it locally.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type commands to be sent to web servers 1-8.  Use ctrl+c to exit."

function getCommand() {
  read thisCmd
  echo "Sending '$thisCmd'..."
  if [ ! -z "$thisCmd" ]; then
    # Run command locally
    echo "From web1"
    cd ~
    command $thisCmd
    # Send to remotes
    for i in {2..8}
    do
      echo "From web$i..."
      ssh "web$i" "$thisCmd"
    done
  fi
  echo Done
  getCommand
}

getCommand
```

But this is resulting in

```
user@web1:~$ ./sshAll.sh 
Type commands to be sent to web servers 1-8.  Use ctrl+c to exit.
cd html; pwd
Sending 'cd html; pwd'...
From web1
./sshAll.sh: line 11: cd: html;: No such file or directory
From web2...
/home/user/html
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expanding a variable as a command like this:

```
$thisCmd
```

Or this

```
command $thisCmd
```

Bash would only parse it as a single command so ; and the likes would be just considered as an argument or part of it e.g. `html;`

So one basic solution to that is to use eval:

```
eval "$thisCmd"
```

But it's a little dangerous. Still it's just the same as those you send to the remote servers. You still execute them like how eval does it.